# Wordpress Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - Jquery Tag-it Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, wordpress-theming

I am trying to use Tagit Jquery Plugin, https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it 
Also attaching photo if somebody want to see http://www.imagesup.net/pt-014044890133.png

The page where i am using this code is standlone page, and is called by template_redirect wordpress action
My Code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// Error showing here - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
 $('#tags').tagit({ availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"]});
});
```

Also i am getting same error at tag-it.source code which is as follow

```
$.widget('ui.tagit', {
// Error showing here - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    options: {
        allowDuplicates   : false,
        caseSensitive     : true,
        fieldName         : 'tags',
        placeholderText   : null,   // Sets `placeholder` attr on input field.
        readOnly          : false,  // Disables editing.
        removeConfirmation: false,  // Require confirmation to remove tags.
        tagLimit          : null,   // Max number of tags allowed (null for unlimited).

        // Used for autocomplete, unless you override `autocomplete.source`.
        availableTags     : [],
```

Here is the code for adding scripts to wordpress

```
function ds_enqueue_query_scripts(){

        wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'tagit',get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/tag-it.min.js', 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'tagitcss', DSCSS . 'tagit.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ds_enqueue_query_scripts' );
```

codes apears on page head section, jquery is loading before tagit...which is the way it should be i guess..

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myhostlocal/AgamWordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://myhostlocal/AgamWordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://myhostlocal/AgamWordpress/wp-content/themes/desistation/js/main.js?ver=3.9.1'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://myhostlocal/AgamWordpress/wp-content/themes/desistation/js/tag-it.min.js?ver=3.9.1'></script>
```

Comment: can you the code of page where you included, make sure it is included after jquery file

Comment: You have either not included `tag-it` plugin file or the order of references is incorrect